# List of python modules shipped with QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Where do I find the list of python modules (including their versions) shipped with QGIS on different operating systems? I thought having a look at the python directory in the QGIS directory and in the user profile should show all answers, but that doesn't seem to be the right answer.

I'm developing a QGIS plugin and get some error messages like 'No module named...' on Windows, but not on Linux and Mac.

Comment: Command line `qgis_installation_directory\apps\Python39\Scripts\pip list` ?

Comment: Same as @J.Monticolo . Its bothersome but I am not aware of any centralized list of integrated python modules shipped with QGIS whether for different version of QGIS or different plateforms.

Comment: Ok, I would accept that as answer - but I really would need this list for QGIS LTS (actually 3.22). Could you please post it for Windows and Mac, as I only have access to a Linux machine?